# Gradle : generating a jar from externally compiled classes

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to generate a `jar` from a folder in which I manually compiled my classes.

Here is the task I put in place

```
task toJar (type: Jar) {
    from file('/path/to/classes/dir')
    destinationDir file('/path/to/jars/dir')
    with jar
}
```

But what that task doesn't generate anything.
I've seen may examples with `configurations.compile.collect` but in my case the directory is compiled by an external tool.

How `gradle` can generate a `jar` from externally compiled classes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task should work fine, but you don't really need the `with jar`.

Below is a working example, assuming that the directory with externally compiled classes is `$rootDir/externalClasses` :

```
task toJar(type: Jar) {
    from file("$rootDir/externalClasses")
    destinationDir project.buildDir
    // print each included file for debug purpose
    eachFile { print "included file: $it" }
}
```

Output :

```
> Task :toJar
included file: file 'C:\tmp\gradle-projects\TestGradle\externalClasses\org\mycompany\gradle\MaiApp.class'
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

The result Jar file is then properly created in `$buildDir/`

Can you try to remove the "with jar" line, and add the `eachFile` debug closure in your code?  what is the output?